# How to write between condition in c# using TableQuery in Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to apply between conditions using tablequery azure in C#.

I give one SQL sentence as below -

```
select * from CardEvents where (CAST('20210327' AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(EventStartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(EventEndDate AS DATE))
```

Please give me result in tablequery azure format.

Comment: you need to show what you have tried yourself already. SO is not there do just do all the work for you. Start by reading the docs and applying them until you are actually stuck and you can come here with a concrete problem statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

Comment: Hello, if this answer is helpful, please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the query below and feel free to modify it as per your need:

```
        //other code
       
        var filter1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("xxx", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, DateTimeOffset.Parse("xx"));
        var filter2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("xxx", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, DateTimeOffset.Parse("xx"));
        string combinedFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter1, TableOperators.And, filter2);

        TableQuery query = new TableQuery().Where(combinedFilter);

        //other code
```

**Note:** in table query, this query which is not based on **PartitionKey** will cause table scan, and it may take a few more time. So if possible, please follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query#how-your-choice-of-partitionkey-and-rowkey-impacts-query-performance) to use the most proper way to query your table data.